# Why the algebra of square matrices has only trivial graduation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have found this exercise in a brochure about graded algebras. I have a clue how to solve it, but I am not sure.
Why the algebra of square matrices has only trivial graduation?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the positive part has to be a two-sided ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive part"?

Comment: @CarolineWayne What is a graduation (grading) of an algebra? If you look up the definition, then the positive part is explained as well.